# How can I be global administrator of my Azure portal?

Tags: azure

I signed up for a trial Azure portal account.
Many times however, I see in the portal "admin consent required" and it seems I'm not an admin...
How can I be admin of my own portal I created?

In Enterprise applications | User settings I see the "Admin consent request grayed out" and set to "no"...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s possible to get this if you sign up with an email account that’s already associated with an Enterprise Agreement. It’s best to sign up for a trail account with a Live ID or similar and use in private browsing to initially set up so the portal doesn’t pick up any saved credentials.

Comment: Actually if I enter the free trial Azure account I get: "Your current account type is not supported" Create a new account and sign up. If you are an IT admin, you can take over the directory.
However I can enter the Azure portal account: https://portal.azure.com/ where I see everything but I'm not the admin. It's pretty confusing. Should I "Take over the directory?" I'm trying to read it, it's pretty long. I want just to start using it.

Comment: I tried 1. Create New account.

Sorry, but we’re having trouble with signing you in.

AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '8e0e8db5-b713-4e91-98e6-470fed0aa4c2'.

Comment: so what I did is maybe a "Self-service sign-up"? and I should take it over in some way?